# How do I find the last rows each machine_id in mysql database with vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
'    machine_id   time_schedule  product_quantity
'        1                            100
'        1                            200          
'        1                            100          <<  find this value(100)
'        2            05:00:00
'        2            10:00:00
'        2            15:00:00                     <<  find this value(15:00:00)
'        3                            100           
'        3                            300          <<  find this value(300)
'        4                            200           
'        4                            100           
'        4                            50           <<  find this value(50)
```

How do I find the last rows each machine_id in mysql database with vb.net?? Thanks

```
    Private Sub btnAddSchedule_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddSchedule.Click
    Try
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(Me.dtpSchedule.Text

        ' PROBLEM IN HERE ??? 
        Dim rwFound As DataRow = MyDataset.Tables("totalizer_setting").Rows.Find( ??? )
        If IsNothing(rwFound) Then
        Dim rw As DataRow = MyDataset.Tables("totalizer_setting").NewRow
        rw("machine_id") = Me.txtMachineID.Text
        rw("time_schedule") = ts
        rw("product_quantity") = DBNull.Value
        MyDataset.Tables("totalizer_setting").Rows.Add(rw)

        Dim sql As String = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0}.totalizer_setting (machine_id, time_schedule, product_quantity) VALUES ({1});", varSchema, "@machine_id, @time_schedule, @product_quantity")
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, objCon)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machine_id", Me.txtMachineID.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time_schedule", ts)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_quantity", DBNull.Value)
        MyDataAdapter.InsertCommand = cmd
        MyDataAdapter.Update(MyDataset, "totalizer_setting")
        cmd.Dispose()

       End If
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error occurred in btnAddSchedule_Click Function" & vbCrLf & ex.Number & " – " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: see accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379565/mysql-first-and-last-record-of-a-grouped-record-aggregate-functions for a more efficient solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
select last(time_schedule), last(product_quality) from yourTable group by machine_id
```

On a second thought, I'm not if mysql has `last()` function (sql server does). If mysql doesn't have it, you can either use `first()` with reverse order or see the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379565/mysql-first-and-last-record-of-a-grouped-record-aggregate-functions)