# mysql - How can I get the first result from a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. Here is a simplified breakdown:

```
Table #1 - Album:
Rows:
albumId | title | userId

Table #2 - Photo:
Rows:
photoId | src | albumId
```

I want to get the first photo's src from each album. This is pretty clearly not what I'm looking for but here is what I have:

```
SELECT pa.id, pa.title, p.src
FROM Album pa
LEFT JOIN Photo p ON pa.Id = p.albumId
WHERE pa.userId = 1
```

That returns all of the photos from the user. I would like the first result for each album in those results.

Comment: If you want to retrieve the albums' covers - you better add the separated column for that, like `cover_photo_id` and have it specified explicitly

Comment: Define "first" in "first result for each album"

Comment: pa.id doesn't exist, it should be pa.albumId ;) just so that other repliers keep that in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may want to add a cover_photo_id, as @zerkms said, but this could do the trick (don't know if using subqueries is efficient enough for your situation)

```
SELECT pa.albumId, pa.title, p.src
FROM Album pa
LEFT JOIN Photo p 
  ON p.photoId = (SELECT MIN(photoId) FROM Photo WHERE albumId = pa.albumId)
WHERE pa.userId = 1
```

Comment: Nope, this would return only one row at all

Comment: You better put that condition to the `ON` part

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pa.id, pa.title, p.src
FROM Album pa
  LEFT JOIN Photo p ON pa.Id = p.albumId
WHERE pa.userId = 1 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: MySQL Error: "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'"

Answer (score -1):

You want to use GROUP BY

```
SELECT pa.id, pa.title, p.src
FROM Album pa
LEFT JOIN Photo p ON pa.Id = p.albumId
WHERE pa.userId = 1
GROUP BY pa.id, pa.title
```

If you actually want the equivalent of a FIRST, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379565/mysql-first-and-last-record-of-a-grouped-record-aggregate-functions)

Comment: And what `p.src` value is supposed to be selected?

Comment: Haha, nice. But it's not April 1st :)

Comment: I'd better go with another magic function `SELECT WHATEVERINEED()`

Comment: if you leave it, it'll just grab the first record

Comment: @pocketfullofcheese: there is no `first` or `last` row until you define an order

Comment: And there is no [`FIRST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/func-op-summary-ref.html) function in MySQL.

Comment: I don't think the OP actually cares about it being the first. He just wants one. So ordering however he wants that last column should do the trick.

Comment: @pocketfullofcheese: if he wanted `any` he would probably say `any`. But he said `first`. It is not a justification to the wrong query (it is wrong at least from ANSI SQL perspective)

Comment: Just gave him a link for how to emulate a FIRST for that last column

Comment: @pocketfullofcheese: `MIN` or `MAX` used with `p.src` wouldn't give first or last row. They would return the least or greatest `p.src`, which is obviously a URL

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT pa.id, pa.title, p.src
FROM Album pa
LEFT JOIN Photo p ON pa.Id = p.albumId
WHERE pa.userId = 1
GROUP BY pa.albumId
ORDER BY p.photoID
```

Comment: you can't get fields that aren't aggregates or that are on the group key... can you?

Comment: @elgerva: Actually you can in MySQL, but the returned data (for `p.src`) is undefined. It can be from any (random) row in the group.

Comment: Yep you can in MySQL. MySQL shouldn't do that I agree. I don't know if it is always the expected row, I just checked a few results and it is fine. Seems like working to me.