# Sql Server: Get OHLC in one query with n recodrs

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2000

I need get OHLC values from one query

```
SELECT [Open] -- first row value
  ,[High] -- max(High)
  ,[Low]  -- min(low)
  ,[Close]-- last row value
FROM [Forex] where Symbol ='EURUSD' and 
[timestamp] between '2013-07-18 01:00:00.000' and '2013-07-18 02:00:00.000'
```

and I want that query has 12 hours details. I mean I need to get 12 records with hourly OHLC values

Can any one help in the query.
[How to fetch the first and last record of a grouped record in a MySQL query with aggregate functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379565/mysql-first-and-last-record-of-a-grouped-record-aggregate-functions/) has implementation in MYSQL, I need in SQL server

Edit: Structure of the the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Forex](
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Symbol] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Bid] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
[Ask] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
[Open] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
[High] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
[Low] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
[NetChange] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
[PerChange] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Forex] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and Index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [index_Forex_29_85575343__K2_K1] ON [dbo].[Forex] 
(
[Symbol] ASC,
[Id] DESC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: It's time to look for an upgrade. 2000 exited even *extended* support in April this year. There have been 4 releases since then and a fifth is currently in preview.

Comment: I can not upgrade,because it a client machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use something like

```
select [open],[min], [max], [close] 
from 
(
   select min(value) [min], max(value) [max] 
   from forex 
   where Symbol ='EURUSD' and 
   [timestamp] between '2013-07-18 01:00:00.000' and '2013-07-18 02:00:00.000'  
) minmax,

(
   select top 1 value as [open] 
   from forex 
   where Symbol ='EURUSD' and 
   [timestamp] between '2013-07-18 01:00:00.000' and '2013-07-18 02:00:00.000' 
   order by [timestamp] 
) fst,

(
  select top 1 value [close] 
  from forex 
  where Symbol ='EURUSD' and 
  [timestamp] between '2013-07-18 01:00:00.000' and '2013-07-18 02:00:00.000' 
  order by [timestamp] desc
) lst
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0547c/2

**EDIT**

Based on revised question...
we can take the min and max id's grouped by time period (hour) together with the min and max values for that hour:

```
select 
   datepart(hh,timestamp) [hour], 
   min(value) [min], 
   max(value) [max],
   min(id) min_id, 
   max(id) max_id 
 from forex 
 where Symbol ='EURUSD' and 
[timestamp] between '2013-07-18 01:00:00.000' and '2013-07-18 13:00:00.000'
 group by datepart(hh,timestamp)
```

and join this with the forex table (twice) to get the open and close values.

Giving something like

```
   select minmax.[hour], f_min.value [open], [min], [max], f_max.value [close] 
    from 
    (select 
       datepart(hh,timestamp) [hour], 
       min(value) [min], 
       max(value) [max],
       min(id) min_id, 
       max(id) max_id 
     from forex 
     where Symbol ='EURUSD' and 
    [timestamp] between '2013-07-18 01:00:00.000' and '2013-07-18 13:00:00.000'
     group by datepart(hh,timestamp)
    ) minmax 
    join forex f_min on min_id = f_min.id
    join forex f_max on max_id = f_max.id
```

*[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7de2b/8)*

Comment: How can I get next hour values? Do I need to run in a loop?

Comment: How can I get weekly, if I want?

Comment: Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265(v=sql.80).aspx it show the datepart function which is used in the query

Answer (score 0):

This helped me

```
select minmax.[hour], f_min.[Open] [open], [min], [max], f_max.Ask [close] 
from 
(select 
   datepart(hh,timestamp) [hour], 
   min(High) [min], 
   max(Low) [max],
   min(id) min_id, 
   max(id) max_id 
 from forex 
 where Symbol ='EURUSD' and 
[timestamp] between '2013-07-18 01:00:00.000' and '2013-07-18 15:00:00.000'
 group by datepart(hh,timestamp) 
)  minmax 
join forex f_min on min_id = f_min.id
join forex f_max on max_id = f_max.id order by [hour]
```