# Retrieve historical data

Tags: mysql

I have a database with records and I need to make a market price history of the last 10 days and I return the price of open and the price of close.

The database is something:

```
ID | MARKET | EXCHANGE | LAST_TRADE | TIMESTAMP
1  |   1    |    1     |     25     | 1392562800 #2014/2/16 @ 15:0:0 <-- "Today's Open" (first insert of the day)
2  |   1    |    1     |     35     | 1392573600 #2014/2/16 @ 18:0:0
3  |   1    |    1     |     45     | 1392584400 #2014/2/16 @ 21:0:0
4  |   1    |    1     |     55     | 1392562800 #2014/2/16 @ 23:59:0 <-- "Today's Close" (last insert of the day)
```

Suppose we have more days, we have to group it by days and return the open and close price that day where the market and exchange = 1

Example:

```
ID | MARKET | EXCHANGE |    DATE   | OPEN | CLOSE
 1 |   1    |    1     | 2014/2/16 |  25  |  55
```

Comment: What format has this timestamp column? Is there really this string inside?

Comment: The timestamp column is int(11), the string is a simple reference comment

Comment: can you please share the schema generation script so that I can check the query at my end before I pass it to you...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/STspkTsU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [converting the timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362874/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-datetime-in-mysql) and grouping by the date only, you can use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552389/314291) to get the first and last rows in the aggregate:

```
select 
  market, 
  exchange, 
  date(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)),
  SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(lastTrade AS CHAR) ORDER BY timestamp), 
         ',', 1 ) as open,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(lastTrade AS CHAR) ORDER BY timestamp DESC), 
         ',', 1 ) as close
from historicdata 
group by market, exchange, date(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp));
```

[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47270/2)

It looks like your timestamp comments don't quite match the actual timestamps - row 1 and 4 both have timestamp `1392562800`. The fiddle also includes an intraday high higher than the close, just as a test case :)

Comment: Awesome!! great :) +1

Comment: Obviously bringing the ID column doesn't really make sense in the grouped result, although you could apply another aggregate to it, e.g. `MIN` or `MAX`